# PSQL Query summing columns on a "has many through" relationship yielding duplicates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, psql

My goal is to generate an ActiveRecordRelation containing each Customer with it's balance *(sale_line_items.total + sale_adjustments.effect_to_balance - sale_payment.amount)*

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord:Base
  has_many :sales

class Sale < ActiveRecord:Base
  belongs_to :customer
  has_many :sale_adjustments
  has_many :sale_payments

class SaleLineItem < ActiveRecord:Base
  belongs_to :sale

class SalePayment < ActiveRecord:Base
  belongs_to :sale

class SaleAdjustment < ActiveRecord:Base
  belongs_to :sale
```

My current code:

```
customers = Customer.all

customers = customers.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN sales ON customers.id = sales.customer_id")
    customers = customers.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN sale_line_items ON sale_line_items.sale_id = sales.id")
    customers = customers.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN sale_adjustments ON sale_adjustments.sale_id = sales.id")
    customers = customers.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN sale_payments ON sale_payments.sale_id = sales.id")
customers = customers.select("customers.*,
    COALESCE(SUM(sale_line_items.total),0) +
    COALESCE(SUM(sale_adjustments.effect_to_balance),0) -
    COALESCE(SUM(sale_payments.amount),0) AS customer_balance")
customers.group("customers.id").distinct
```

The problem is that if there are more than one payments or adjustments, the line items are duplicated in the resulting table, essentially increasing the total by a factor of that number. I think i understand enough to identify the problem, but not enough to come up with a solution. The rails generated query is below.

```
[1m[36mCustomer Load (2.2ms)[0m  [1mSELECT DISTINCT customers.*,
    COALESCE(SUM(sale_line_items.total),0) +
    COALESCE(SUM(sale_adjustments.effect_to_balance),0) -
    COALESCE(SUM(sale_payments.amount),0) AS customer_balance 
    FROM "customers" LEFT OUTER JOIN sales ON customers.id = sales.customer_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sale_line_items ON sale_line_items.sale_id = sales.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sale_adjustments ON sale_adjustments.sale_id = sales.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sale_payments ON sale_payments.sale_id = sales.id 
    WHERE "customers"."business_id" = $1 GROUP BY customers.id[0m  [["business_id", "bd0c474c-db6e-43bc-95ca-90541d3840d1"]]
```

An example of the error is:
A customer with one sale that has one line item of $50

```
total sales: $50, balance: $50
```

Add one payment of $10

```
total sales: $50, balance: $40
```

Problems occur on the second payment, lets say $1

```
total sales $100, balance $89
```

That extra payment creates a duplicate row for the line item. It will go to $150 on a third payment and so on...

Any help is greatly appreciated - i've been working on this all night and at this point i'm just going around in circles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked on something similar while I was calculating invoice balance for a PHP-MySQL project. I ended up changing my database structure and application flow. I modified the invoices table to include `invoice_total` and `total_payment` columns which will be updated with creation and edition of Invoice and Payment modules.

Although you can use sub-queries to get the desired result like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT customers.*,
COALESCE(SUM(sli.total),0) +
COALESCE(SUM(sa.effect_to_balance),0) -
COALESCE(SUM(sp.amount),0) AS customer_balance 
FROM "customers" LEFT OUTER JOIN sales ON customers.id = sales.customer_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT sale_id, SUM(total) total FROM sale_line_items) sli ON sli.sale_id = sales.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT sale_id, SUM(effect_to_balance) effect_to_balance FROM sale_adjustments) sa ON sa.sale_id = sales.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT sale_id, SUM(amount) amountFROM sale_payments) sp ON sp.sale_id = sales.id 
WHERE "customers"."business_id" = $1 GROUP BY customers.id
```

Hope this will solve your problem :)

Comment: Apologies for not selecting or responding to your helpful post sooner. Both of your solutions work - i chose to go with subqueries modeled after your example. I'm including my ruby code as an additional answer in the chance that it may assist someone else with a similar problem. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The rails code modeled after Manoj Monga's answer:

```
customers = Customer.all

customers = customers.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN sales ON customers.id = sales.customer_id")

customers = customers.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT sale_id, SUM(total) total FROM sale_line_items GROUP BY sale_id) sli ON sli.sale_id = sales.id")
customers = customers.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT sale_id, SUM(effect_to_balance) effect_to_balance FROM sale_adjustments GROUP BY sale_id) sa ON sa.sale_id = sales.id")
customers = customers.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT sale_id, SUM(amount) amount FROM sale_payments GROUP BY sale_id) sp ON sp.sale_id = sales.id")

customers = customers.select("customers.*,
    COALESCE(SUM(total), 0) as sales_total,
    COALESCE(SUM(total), 0) + 
    COALESCE(SUM(effect_to_balance),0) - 
    COALESCE(SUM(amount),0) AS customer_balance")
customers.group("customers.id").distinct
```